# getInstalledPackages() for Android multiple users

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-multiple-users

I want to get a list of all apps installed on my device. My code is below:

`PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);`

When I try multiple user registered on my device (i.e. Android for Work), the API returns a list from the same user space/managed profile, which makes sense.

My question is, is there an option to get a list of all apps from the device (like Settings - Apps - All apps), no matter where the app is installed?

Comment: That sounds like a violation of user space sandboxing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your reply. Yes I agree with you. For the system settings "all apps" page, is it based on a private API?

Answer (score 1):

Use LauncherApps (only can get apps will shown in launcher), you can see how Launcher3 use it
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html